# Violation of Liskov Substitution Principle in SharedFolder

Tags: oop, inheritance, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

The current design is

1. `SharedFolder` is a subclass of `Folder`.
2. `SharedFile` is a subclass of `File` with a remote resource URL.
3. `Folder` accepts `File` in an `add` method.
4. `SharedFolder` accepts only `SharedFile` but not non-shared `File`
5. `File` can be moved to another `Folder` with `add`.
6. The UI for browsing files in `SharedFolder` and `Folder` is mostly the same.

The `add` in `SharedFile` violate LSP. How to re-organize the object structure while allowing some UI code reuse?

Comment: You could define the add method to not contractually guarantee that adding is possible in all cases. That way there is no substitution failure.

Comment: @usr, are you saying that documentation alone can satisfy LSP? In that case, even the notorious [Iterator.remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) method satisfies LSP.

Comment: Static typing is just a way to add *some* documentation in a machine-readable way. An interface contract is arbitrary. It is whatever you define. Don't get hung up on syntax or language issues.

Comment: As a concrete solution you could add this method: `bool TryAdd(File f)` and allow folders to reject items for any reason. That way you can surface this in the UI by telling the user "this file can't go here". Throwing would also work. Exceptions are just another way of returning something.

Comment: I agree with @usr, not all the rules and invariants must be enforced through type checking. I'd throw an exception here or return `AddResult` rather than a `bool` which wouldn't really allow the client to know what went wrong.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/170138/is-this-a-violation-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle explains why this is a bad idea

Comment: You can define the pre- and postconditions any way you like. If you define the precondition to be nothing and the postcondition to either return ok or rejected then it's not an LSP violation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can genericize `Folder` as `Folder<T extends File>`, with `add(T)`, and have `SharedFolder extends Folder<SharedFile>`.

This way, `SharedFolder` is only expected to substitute another `Folder<SharedFile>`, but not any other type of `Folder<File>`

(If your language allows it. This would be possible in Java)

Comment: Presumably he needs to be able to store any folder type in a variable. Then, the generic constraint information is lost and the LSP violation comes back.

Comment: if you are using any folder type, you can't store any file type in that folder. You can't just get rid of the generic constraint.

Answer (score 3):

There are many possible answers to your question. Here are two:

- Remove the `add` method from the `Folder` base class, and only let it expose a (readonly) collection of `File` elements.
- Remove the 'is a' relationship between `SharedFolder` and `Folder`. In other words, don't let `SharedFolder` inherit from `Folder`. Instead you could let `SharedFolder` become some sort of metadata class that contains a `Folder` (composition over inheritance).

Comment: How does the first answer satisfy LSP? Would the collection need to be immutable? Otherwise, the offending `add()` method has simply moved to the collection.

Comment: @jaco0646 this solves the problem, because consumers of the base class will be unable to call `add` and insert items that are incompatible with the derived class contract.

Comment: ...but presumably the consumer can still call `getCollection().add()` which would fail in the same scenario as the original `add()`.

Comment: @jaco0646: Ah yes, I forgot to mention that the collection should be readonly from the outside.

Comment: How to reuse code if design 2 is used? Usually, composition requires abstract interface.

Comment: @keithyip: When you compose objects, you get often much better reuse than if you use inheritance. Your milleage might vary though and whether the trait is good is not something I can comment on. That is something you will have to decide for your self.

Comment: I just want to see if there are any concrete techniques to solve this kind of problems. I have seen them from time to time. There are not many case studies on the internet. Most of them are just the introduction of composition over inheritance using the square rectangle example.

Comment: @keithyip I really 'solid' book on this subject is Robert Martin's [APP&P](https://www.amazon.com/Software-Development-Principles-Patterns-Practices/dp/0135974445/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1470378300&sr=1-2&keywords=Agile+Principles%2C+Patterns%2C+and+Practices). This is a must read. It goes into details about the LSP and the other 4 SOLID principles. Let me say this again: A must read.